# Prove $l_{ip}=\frac{\partial \bar x_i}{\partial x_p}=\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial \bar x_i}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, rotations, fluid-dynamics

Let $l$ be a rotation tensor such that

$$\bar x_i=l_{ip}x_p$$

where $l_{ip}$ is the direction cosine between the unit vectors in the component directions $x_p$ and $\bar x_i$. Prove that

$$l_{ip}=\frac{\partial \bar x_i}{\partial x_p}=\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial \bar x_i}$$

---

**Hint**

Use this property of the rotation tensor

$$l{l^T} = I$$

Comment: Where is $L$ suppose to appear? Right now it seems like there's nothing to show.

Comment: @Jeb I think $L$ is just the matrix of $l_{ij}$ with i and j = 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let us start from

$${\bar x_i} = {l_{ip}}{x_p}\tag{1}$$

Now, we take the derivative with respect to $x_k$ to obtain

$${{\partial {{\bar x}_i}} \over {\partial {x_k}}} = {l_{ip}}{{\partial {x_p}} \over {\partial {x_k}}} = {l_{ip}}{\delta _{pk}} = {l_{ik}}\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,{l_{ip}} = {{\partial {{\bar x}_i}} \over {\partial {x_p}}}\tag{2}$$

Next, we note that $l_{ip}$ has the following property that its inverse is equal to its transpose. This is called orthogonality. Hence, we can write this property in index form as

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{l{l^T} = I}& \to &{l = {{\left( {{l^{ - 1}}} \right)}^T}}\\
{{l_{ip}}{l_{kp}} = {\delta _{ik}}}& \to &{{l_{ip}} = {{\left( {{l^{ - 1}}} \right)}^T}_{ip}}
\end{array}\tag{3}$$

On the other hand, we have

$$\eqalign{
  & {\left( {{l^{ - 1}}} \right)_{ip}} = {{\partial {x_i}} \over {\partial {{\bar x}_p}}}  \cr 
  & {\left( {{l^{ - 1}}} \right)^T}_{ip} = {{\partial {x_p}} \over {\partial {{\bar x}_i}}} \cr}\tag{4}$$

Finally, combine $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ to get

$${l_{ip}} = {{\partial {{\bar x}_i}} \over {\partial {x_p}}} = {{\partial {x_p}} \over {\partial {{\bar x}_i}}}\tag{5}$$

Comment: I am a bit confused why it isn't written as $(l_{ip})^T$ instead of the what you done which is put the ip outside the bracket....? Thanks so much for taking a look btw.

Comment: @snowman: Suppose that $A$ is some tensor. How do you show its components? $A_{ij} $right? Now, what if $A=B^T$? Then it is reasonable to write $A_{ij}=(B^T)_{ij}$. In fact, $(B_{ij})^T=B_{ij}$  as the transpose of a scalar equals itself but $(B^T)_{ij}=B_{ji}$. :)

Comment: @snowman: Any other ambiguities?

Comment: Ok but I dont see how writing $(l^{-1})_{ij}^T$ makes sense because these are components so they're fixed terms. How can you take a transpose of a term....

Comment: @snowman: Oooops! Consider $(l^{-1})^T$ just as the letter $A$! That's all! Then try to write down the components! :) Take a look at $(3)$ and the question again, I changed it a little so that you can understand better.